# How to connect checkout of PayPal with IWebBrowser2 in c++winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi, paypal, com

So I'm making checkout for paypal in c++ winapi. Checkout link from Buy now buuton link. And for it I've used CLSID_WEBBROWSER new WebBrowser type(COM IWebBrowser2). So when I navigate it to PayPal Site. It says The Web Browser is older version. How can I navigate to this site with this WebBrowser

WebBrowser.h:

```cpp
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Exdisp.h>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

class WebBrowser :
    public IOleClientSite,
    public IOleInPlaceSite,
    public IStorage
{

public:

    WebBrowser(HWND hWndParent);

    bool CreateBrowser();

    RECT PixelToHiMetric(const RECT& _rc);

    virtual void SetRect(const RECT& _rc);

    // ----- Control methods -----

    void GoBack();

    void GoForward();

    void Refresh();

    void Navigate(wstring szUrl);

    // ----- IUnknown -----

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid,
        void** ppvObject) override;

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef(void);

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release(void);

    // ---------- IOleWindow ----------

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetWindow(
        __RPC__deref_out_opt HWND* phwnd) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ContextSensitiveHelp(
        BOOL fEnterMode) override;

    // ---------- IOleInPlaceSite ----------

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CanInPlaceActivate(void) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnInPlaceActivate(void) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnUIActivate(void) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetWindowContext(
        __RPC__deref_out_opt IOleInPlaceFrame** ppFrame,
        __RPC__deref_out_opt IOleInPlaceUIWindow** ppDoc,
        __RPC__out LPRECT lprcPosRect,
        __RPC__out LPRECT lprcClipRect,
        __RPC__inout LPOLEINPLACEFRAMEINFO lpFrameInfo) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Scroll(
        SIZE scrollExtant) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnUIDeactivate(
        BOOL fUndoable) override;

    virtual HWND GetControlWindow();

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnInPlaceDeactivate(void) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DiscardUndoState(void) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DeactivateAndUndo(void) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnPosRectChange(
        __RPC__in LPCRECT lprcPosRect) override;

    // ---------- IOleClientSite ----------

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SaveObject(void) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetMoniker(
        DWORD dwAssign,
        DWORD dwWhichMoniker,
        __RPC__deref_out_opt IMoniker** ppmk) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetContainer(
        __RPC__deref_out_opt IOleContainer** ppContainer) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ShowObject(void) override;
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnShowWindow(
        BOOL fShow) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE RequestNewObjectLayout(void) override;

    // ----- IStorage -----

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateStream(
        __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR* pwcsName,
        DWORD grfMode,
        DWORD reserved1,
        DWORD reserved2,
        __RPC__deref_out_opt IStream** ppstm) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OpenStream(
        const OLECHAR* pwcsName,
        void* reserved1,
        DWORD grfMode,
        DWORD reserved2,
        IStream** ppstm) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateStorage(
        __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR* pwcsName,
        DWORD grfMode,
        DWORD reserved1,
        DWORD reserved2,
        __RPC__deref_out_opt IStorage** ppstg) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OpenStorage(
        __RPC__in_opt_string const OLECHAR* pwcsName,
        __RPC__in_opt IStorage* pstgPriority,
        DWORD grfMode,
        __RPC__deref_opt_in_opt SNB snbExclude,
        DWORD reserved,
        __RPC__deref_out_opt IStorage** ppstg) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CopyTo(
        DWORD ciidExclude,
        const IID* rgiidExclude,
        __RPC__in_opt  SNB snbExclude,
        IStorage* pstgDest) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE MoveElementTo(
        __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR* pwcsName,
        __RPC__in_opt IStorage* pstgDest,
        __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR* pwcsNewName,
        DWORD grfFlags) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Commit(
        DWORD grfCommitFlags) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Revert(void) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EnumElements(
        DWORD reserved1,
        void* reserved2,
        DWORD reserved3,
        IEnumSTATSTG** ppenum) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DestroyElement(
        __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR* pwcsName) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE RenameElement(
        __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR* pwcsOldName,
        __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR* pwcsNewName) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetElementTimes(
        __RPC__in_opt_string const OLECHAR* pwcsName,
        __RPC__in_opt const FILETIME* pctime,
        __RPC__in_opt const FILETIME* patime,
        __RPC__in_opt const FILETIME* pmtime) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetClass(
        __RPC__in REFCLSID clsid) override;
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetStateBits(
        DWORD grfStateBits,
        DWORD grfMask) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Stat(
        __RPC__out STATSTG* pstatstg,
        DWORD grfStatFlag) override;

protected:

    IOleObject* oleObject;
    IOleInPlaceObject* oleInPlaceObject;

    IWebBrowser2* webBrowser2;

    LONG iComRefCount;

    RECT rObject;

    HWND hWndParent;
    HWND hWndControl;

};
```

Resource.cpp:

```cpp
#include "WebBrowser.h"

WebBrowser::WebBrowser(HWND _hWndParent)
{
    iComRefCount = 0;
    ::SetRect(&rObject, -300, -300, 300, 300);
    hWndParent = _hWndParent;

    if (CreateBrowser() == FALSE)
    {
        return;
    }

    ShowWindow(GetControlWindow(), SW_SHOW);

    this->Navigate(_T("about:blank"));
}

bool WebBrowser::CreateBrowser()
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = ::OleCreate(CLSID_WebBrowser,
        IID_IOleObject, OLERENDER_DRAW, 0, this, this,
        (void**)& oleObject);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Cannot create oleObject CLSID_WebBrowser"),
            _T("Error"),
            MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    hr = oleObject->SetClientSite(this);
    hr = OleSetContainedObject(oleObject, TRUE);

    RECT posRect;
    ::SetRect(&posRect, -300, -300, 300, 300);
    hr = oleObject->DoVerb(OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE,
        NULL, this, -1, hWndParent, &posRect);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("oleObject->DoVerb() failed"),
            _T("Error"),
            MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    hr = oleObject->QueryInterface(&webBrowser2);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("oleObject->QueryInterface(&webBrowser2) failed"),
            _T("Error"),
            MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

RECT WebBrowser::PixelToHiMetric(const RECT& _rc)
{
    static bool s_initialized = false;
    static int s_pixelsPerInchX, s_pixelsPerInchY;
    if (!s_initialized)
    {
        HDC hdc = ::GetDC(0);
        s_pixelsPerInchX = ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX);
        s_pixelsPerInchY = ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY);
        ::ReleaseDC(0, hdc);
        s_initialized = true;
    }

    RECT rc;
    rc.left = MulDiv(2540, _rc.left, s_pixelsPerInchX);
    rc.top = MulDiv(2540, _rc.top, s_pixelsPerInchY);
    rc.right = MulDiv(2540, _rc.right, s_pixelsPerInchX);
    rc.bottom = MulDiv(2540, _rc.bottom, s_pixelsPerInchY);
    return rc;
}

void WebBrowser::SetRect(const RECT& _rc)
{
    rObject = _rc;

    {
        RECT hiMetricRect = PixelToHiMetric(rObject);
        SIZEL sz;
        sz.cx = hiMetricRect.right - hiMetricRect.left;
        sz.cy = hiMetricRect.bottom - hiMetricRect.top;
        oleObject->SetExtent(DVASPECT_CONTENT, &sz);
    }

    if (oleInPlaceObject != 0)
    {
        oleInPlaceObject->SetObjectRects(&rObject, &rObject);
    }
}

// ----- Control methods -----

void WebBrowser::GoBack()
{
    this->webBrowser2->GoBack();
}

void WebBrowser::GoForward()
{
    this->webBrowser2->GoForward();
}

void WebBrowser::Refresh()
{
    this->webBrowser2->Refresh();
}

void WebBrowser::Navigate(wstring szUrl)
{
    bstr_t url(szUrl.c_str());
    variant_t flags(0x02u); //navNoHistory
    this->webBrowser2->Navigate(url, &flags, 0, 0, 0);
}

// ----- IUnknown -----

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::QueryInterface(REFIID riid,
    void** ppvObject)
{
    if (riid == __uuidof(IUnknown))
    {
        (*ppvObject) = static_cast<IOleClientSite*>(this);
    }
    else if (riid == __uuidof(IOleInPlaceSite))
    {
        (*ppvObject) = static_cast<IOleInPlaceSite*>(this);
    }
    else
    {
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    AddRef();
    return S_OK;
}

ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::AddRef(void)
{
    iComRefCount++;
    return iComRefCount;
}

ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::Release(void)
{
    iComRefCount--;
    return iComRefCount;
}

// ---------- IOleWindow ----------

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::GetWindow(
    __RPC__deref_out_opt HWND* phwnd)
{
    (*phwnd) = hWndParent;
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::ContextSensitiveHelp(
    BOOL fEnterMode)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

// ---------- IOleInPlaceSite ----------

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::CanInPlaceActivate(void)
{
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::OnInPlaceActivate(void)
{
    OleLockRunning(oleObject, TRUE, FALSE);
    oleObject->QueryInterface(&oleInPlaceObject);
    oleInPlaceObject->SetObjectRects(&rObject, &rObject);

    return S_OK;

}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::OnUIActivate(void)
{
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::GetWindowContext(
    __RPC__deref_out_opt IOleInPlaceFrame** ppFrame,
    __RPC__deref_out_opt IOleInPlaceUIWindow** ppDoc,
    __RPC__out LPRECT lprcPosRect,
    __RPC__out LPRECT lprcClipRect,
    __RPC__inout LPOLEINPLACEFRAMEINFO lpFrameInfo)
{
    HWND hwnd = hWndParent;

    (*ppFrame) = NULL;
    (*ppDoc) = NULL;
    (*lprcPosRect).left = rObject.left;
    (*lprcPosRect).top = rObject.top;
    (*lprcPosRect).right = rObject.right;
    (*lprcPosRect).bottom = rObject.bottom;
    *lprcClipRect = *lprcPosRect;

    lpFrameInfo->fMDIApp = false;
    lpFrameInfo->hwndFrame = hwnd;
    lpFrameInfo->haccel = NULL;
    lpFrameInfo->cAccelEntries = 0;

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::Scroll(
    SIZE scrollExtant)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::OnUIDeactivate(
    BOOL fUndoable)
{
    return S_OK;
}

HWND WebBrowser::GetControlWindow()
{
    if (hWndControl != 0)
        return hWndControl;

    if (oleInPlaceObject == 0)
        return 0;

    oleInPlaceObject->GetWindow(&hWndControl);
    return hWndControl;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::OnInPlaceDeactivate(void)
{
    hWndControl = 0;
    oleInPlaceObject = 0;

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::DiscardUndoState(void)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::DeactivateAndUndo(void)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::OnPosRectChange(
    __RPC__in LPCRECT lprcPosRect)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

// ---------- IOleClientSite ----------

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::SaveObject(void)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::GetMoniker(
    DWORD dwAssign,
    DWORD dwWhichMoniker,
    __RPC__deref_out_opt IMoniker** ppmk)
{
    if ((dwAssign == OLEGETMONIKER_ONLYIFTHERE) &&
        (dwWhichMoniker == OLEWHICHMK_CONTAINER))
        return E_FAIL;

    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::GetContainer(
    __RPC__deref_out_opt IOleContainer** ppContainer)
{
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::ShowObject(void)
{
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::OnShowWindow(
    BOOL fShow)
{
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::RequestNewObjectLayout(void)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

// ----- IStorage -----

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::CreateStream(
    __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR* pwcsName,
    DWORD grfMode,
    DWORD reserved1,
    DWORD reserved2,
    __RPC__deref_out_opt IStream** ppstm)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::OpenStream(
    const OLECHAR* pwcsName,
    void* reserved1,
    DWORD grfMode,
    DWORD reserved2,
    IStream** ppstm)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::CreateStorage(
    __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR* pwcsName,
    DWORD grfMode,
    DWORD reserved1,
    DWORD reserved2,
    __RPC__deref_out_opt IStorage** ppstg)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::OpenStorage(
    __RPC__in_opt_string const OLECHAR* pwcsName,
    __RPC__in_opt IStorage* pstgPriority,
    DWORD grfMode,
    __RPC__deref_opt_in_opt SNB snbExclude,
    DWORD reserved,
    __RPC__deref_out_opt IStorage** ppstg)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::CopyTo(
    DWORD ciidExclude,
    const IID* rgiidExclude,
    __RPC__in_opt  SNB snbExclude,
    IStorage* pstgDest)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::MoveElementTo(
    __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR* pwcsName,
    __RPC__in_opt IStorage* pstgDest,
    __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR* pwcsNewName,
    DWORD grfFlags)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::Commit(
    DWORD grfCommitFlags)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::Revert(void)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::EnumElements(
    DWORD reserved1,
    void* reserved2,
    DWORD reserved3,
    IEnumSTATSTG** ppenum)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::DestroyElement(
    __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR* pwcsName)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::RenameElement(
    __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR* pwcsOldName,
    __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR* pwcsNewName)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::SetElementTimes(
    __RPC__in_opt_string const OLECHAR* pwcsName,
    __RPC__in_opt const FILETIME* pctime,
    __RPC__in_opt const FILETIME* patime,
    __RPC__in_opt const FILETIME* pmtime)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::SetClass(
    __RPC__in REFCLSID clsid)
{
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::SetStateBits(
    DWORD grfStateBits,
    DWORD grfMask)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::Stat(
    __RPC__out STATSTG* pstatstg,
    DWORD grfStatFlag)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
```

Testing.cpp:

```cpp
WebBrowser* pBrowser2;



if (SUCCEEDED(OleInitialize(NULL)))
                {
MoneyHWND = CreateDialog(GetModuleHandle(0), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_FORMVIEW1), hWnd, MoneyProc);
pBrowser2 = new WebBrowser(MoneyHWND);
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(MoneyHWND, &rc);
pBrowser2->SetRect(rc);

pBrowser2->Navigate(L"Paypal site");


OleUninitialize();
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a per-application registry setting that makes IWebBrowser2 use newer IE versions. You can use IE 11 emulation mode.

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)#browser_emulation).

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
SOFTWARE
  Microsoft
     Internet Explorer
        Main
           FeatureControl
              FEATURE_BEHAVIORS
                 appname.exe = (DWORD) 00000000
```

Change the word to the desired IE version. Sample code with my [registry wrapper](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1040618/Happy-Registry-A-quick-wrapper-for-the-Win-databas):

```
// Browser Emulation
vector<wchar_t> fn(1000);
GetModuleFileName(0, fn.data(), 1000);
PathStripPath(fn.data());
RKEY k(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION");
k[fn.data()] = 11001UL; // Use IE 11
```

Note that UWP allows using MapView (Edge engine), but this is only available in UWP, not desktop apps (even with Xaml Islands).

Comment: Thanks for code. Can you send code with HKEY. My compilator didn't understand what is RKEY. I have already added class to end of .cpp. But compilator gives error.

Comment: It uses my [Registry Wrapper](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1040618/Happy-Registry-A-quick-wrapper-for-the-Win-databas) but it's simply a matter of setting a DWORD at the specified position.

Comment: I believe Edge is available for Win32 apps now.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest using WinHttpClient instead, and when you redirect the user to the PayPal login page, the default browser will be opened.
The WinHttpClient class was developed by [shicheng](http://shicheng) and can be found in [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66625/A-Fully-Featured-Windows-HTTP-Wrapper-in-C) article.

[Here is](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1225092/Integrating-with-PayPal-smoothly) my own article about implementing PayPal Quick Checkout.

Send string to PayPal server

```
WinHttpClient WinClient1(ExpChkoutStr.GetBuffer());
WinClient1.SetRequireValidSslCertificates(false);
```

Now we get PayPal's response:

```
WinClient1.SendHttpRequest(L"GET");
httpResponseContent1 = WinClient1.GetResponseContent();
CString strTransactionRet = UrlDecode(httpResponseContent1.c_str());
```

The response is parsed using the following code:

```
// Extract token from response
CString sToken = ExtractElement(strTransactionRet, L"TOKEN");

if (sToken == L"")
{
    wprintf(L"Internal error: (Paypal): no token was generated (%s)", strTransactionRet);
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Internal payment processing error", L"", MB_OK);
    return FALSE;
}
CString LinkToOpen = (m_sandbox) ? SANDBOX_PAYPAL_CHECKOUT : REAL_PAYPAL_CHECKOUT;

LinkToOpen += L"&token=";
LinkToOpen += sToken;
```

Comment: It s variant too. But SandBox is for developers.

Comment: My code contains whatever you need for the real paypal account as well. Not just the sandbox.
See CString LinkToOpen = (m_sandbox) ? SANDBOX_PAYPAL_CHECKOUT : REAL_PAYPAL_CHECKOUT;